# C:\Programs\ - is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file, command, external, command-prompt, internal

I tried to run the command but I get the following error.

[image]

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that your bat file has a bad path in it.

Answer (score 2):

In the windows command prompt, any time a pathname has a space in it (such as `C:\PROGRAM FILES`), you must enclose the entire path/filename in quotation marks `"`. In this particular question, the line in `1-startTomcat.bat` that reads `C:\Program Files\SCASec\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin\startup.bat` needs to read `"C:\Program Files\SCASec\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin\startup.bat"`

Comment: It isn't "any time" a path has spaces in it. You don't need to quote the argument for the `cd` and `pushd` commands, for example. Also, an external program can parse its command line anyway it wants, e.g. some allow quoting with single quotes in addition to or instead of double quotes. But the path to run an external program definitely has to be quoted with double quotes if it has spaces in it; otherwise cmd can't find it.